# Why I and j are not aliases

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

here is the code:

```
int main() {
   int i = 0;
   int &j = i;
   j = 10;
   return i;
}
```

and its ir with O0 level optimization:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse nounwind optnone uwtable mustprogress
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 !dbg !7 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  %j = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %i, metadata !11, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !12
  store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4, !dbg !12
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32** %j, metadata !13, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !15
  store i32* %i, i32** %j, align 8, !dbg !15
  %0 = load i32*, i32** %j, align 8, !dbg !16
  store i32 10, i32* %0, align 4, !dbg !17
  %1 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4, !dbg !18
  ret i32 %1, !dbg !19
}
```

and use command:

```
opt -disable-basic-aa --cfl-steens-aa -aa-eval print-all-alias-modref-info e0.ll
```

get result:

```
  NoAlias:      i32* %i, i32* %retval
  NoAlias:      i32* %retval, i32** %j
  NoAlias:      i32* %i, i32** %j
  NoAlias:      i32* %0, i32* %retval
  MayAlias:     i32* %0, i32* %i
  NoAlias:      i32* %0, i32** %j
```

Does anyone know why the result is 'MayAlias'.

Comment: You could hardly get NoAlias in this case.

Comment: I think they should be ‘MustAlias'，because `%0` and `%i` point to the same memory location, but it is not.

Comment: And in fact, the alias relationship between `i` and `j` is not returned correctly. I wonder how to get the correct alias relationship for this code with LLVM.